# How can I create my own dot operator function for a string?

Tags: c++

I'm a student. Let's say I want to be able to do my_string.reverse();. I don't want to see the actual code to reverse a string, I just want to see how this function would be implemented for strings.

A side question: why have I never seen this dot operator used with types such as int or char, is that simply not possible?

Comment: What do you mean "my own dot operator function"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the proper terminology. What I mean is ".some_function_i_created(); that belongs to the string type."

Comment: You should go through [basic tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload the member access operator; and you can't add members to an already defined class. If the type of `my_string` doesn't have a `reverse` member, and you can't (or don't want to) add one to the class definition, then you simply can't do anything to provide that syntax.

If you want to write a function to manipulate a class without changing the class definition, it will have to be a non-member function, called as e.g. `reverse(my_string)`.

> why have I never seen this dot operator used with types such as int or char, is that simply not possible?

No it isn't. The language only defines that operator for class types, and doesn't allow it to be overloaded.